# Is there any way to get command line parameters in Google Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, command-line, google-chrome-extension

I need to launch Chrome from command line with custom parameter, which
contains path to some js-file. Further this path will be used in
extension.

I browsed carefully all related documentation and clicked all nodes in
Chrome debugger, but found nothing which can resemble on command line
parameters. Is it possible anyway to get these parameters or it's need
to write more complex npapi-extension? (theoretically in such npapi-
extension we able to get self process through win-api, command line of
self process and so on).

Comment: FYI, the NPAPI approach you described won't work, because the plugin would be running in a completely different process (launched by Chrome with command line parameters it decides on).

Comment: You're wrong and right simultaneously. I tried such scheme already, and it's possible get info about separate current process with extension. It means that also there is way to get info about parent process and about parent process command line as result.

Comment: Also I found special page chrome://version. This page contains exact info what I need - command line with all switches. I tried debug this page, but found nothing useful for me.

Comment: The data displayed on `chrome://version` is defined in `chrome://version/strings.js` but extensions aren't allowed to access it.

Answer (score 9):

Hack alert: [this post](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-extensions/msg/4599ffef0e186a06) suggests passing a fake URL to open that has all the command-line parameters as query string parameters, e.g.,

```
chrome.exe http://fakeurl.com/?param1=val1&param2=val2
```

Comment: +1 Thanks! I refined this approach a bit, pls. check out my answer. I would be happy to hear your opinion.

Comment: Works...might also want to prefix with `./` like `./chrome.exe MY_URL`

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps pass the path to your extension in a custom user agent string set via the command line. For example:

```
chrome.exe --user-agent='Chrome 43. My path is:/path/to/file'
```

Then, in your extension:

```
var path = navigator.userAgent.split(":");
console.log(path[1])
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically I use the technique given in [@dfrankow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9381181/600135), but I open `127.0.0.1:0` instead of a fake URL. This approach has two advantages:

1. **The name resolution attempt is skipped.** OK, if I've chosen the fake URL carefully to avoid opening an existing URL, the name resolution would fail for sure. But there is no need for it, so why not just skip this step?
2. **No server listens on TCP port `0`.** Using simply `127.0.0.1` is not enough, since it is possible that a web server runs on the client machine, and I don't want the extension to connect to it accidentally. So I have to specify a port number, but which one? Port `0` is the perfect choice: according to [RFC 1700](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1700.txt), this port number is "reserved", that is, servers are not allowed to use it.

Example command line to pass arguments `abc` and `xyz` to your extension:

```
chrome "http://127.0.0.1:0/?abc=42&xyz=hello"
```

You can read these arguments in background.js this way:

```
chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function (window) {
    chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tabs) {
        var args = { abc: null, xyz: null }, argName, regExp, match;
        for (argName in args) {
            regExp = new RegExp(argName + "=([^\&]+)")
            match = regExp.exec(tabs[0].url);
            if (!match) return;
            args[argName] = match[1];
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(args));
    });
});
```

Console output (in the console of the background page of the extension):

```
{"abc":"42","xyz":"hello"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
var versionPage = "chrome://version/strings.js";
$.post(versionPage, function(data){
    data = data.replace("var templateData = ", "");
    data = data.slice(0, -1);
    var jsonOb = $.parseJSON(data);
    alert(jsonOb.command_line);
});
```

This assumes you are using jQuery in your loading sequence, you could always substitute with any other AJAX method

Comment: This method only works if you have the version page open, to fix this I would wrap the $.post with:

    `chrome.tabs.create({url: versionPage, active: false}, function(){
    });`

Comment: Perhaps once the post is complete you can then close the tab :)

Comment: this technique used to work, but not anymore on chrome 47. I am now using the --user-agent technique with great success.

Answer (score 0):

Further to the answers above about using the URL to pass parameters in, note that only Extensions, not Apps, can do this. I've published a Chrome Extension that just intercepts the URL and makes it available to another App.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gafgnggdglmjplpklcfhcgfaeehecepg/

The source code is available at:

https://github.com/appazur/kiosk-launcher

for [Wi-Fi Public Display Screens](http://www.appazur.com)

Comment: Both links are dead

Comment: sorry, yes, I changed to using group policy to get parameters to my app, so unpublished that.