# Passing information from command line into Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, command-line-arguments, chromium

I want to be able to change the behaviour of my Chrome extension in certain cases. I control the launch of Chrome so I can add any [command line flag](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) to achieve this (preferably not one that changes the behaviour of Chrome).

I need this information to be available in the background page of the extension (not in content pages).

One thing I thought of was adding an environment variable, but apparently this [isn't directly available from the extensions context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22916511/read-environment-variable-from-google-chrome-extension).

I tried looking through the command line switches in [Chromium's code](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc) and thought I may be able to use `test-name`.

Is the `test-name` available in the extension? If not is there another way to pass information into a chrome extension?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to send information to an extension directly.

You need to use messaging one way or another.

- You could use [Chrome Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) to communicate with a python script for example.
- Or you could use [web messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage) to post a message from a web page (which could be a file:// URL).

  - You could try [selenium](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started) to execute the script directly.

```py
    from selenium import webdriver

    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
    driver.get('file:///some/page.html')
    driver.execute_script('chrome.runtime.sendMessage("extensionID", "message");')
    driver.quit()
```

- [Another extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external) could take care of the messaging for you.

Answer (score 3):

Similar question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725845/is-there-any-way-to-get-command-line-parameters-in-google-chrome-extension/31436010).
If you control launch of Chrome, you can pass parameters to extension using fake url:

```
chrome.exe http://fakeurl.com/?param1=val1&param2=val2
```

Your extension can intercept `fakeurl.com`, parse parameters and navigate to another page.

Comment: Note that fakeurl.com is a valid domain name - better use something that is reserved, such as http://myextension.invalid/...

Comment: A nice workaround ✨