# Is it possible to trigger a plugin action via command line in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Let's say I have a couple of scripts that I inject in a web-application like this:

popup.js:

```
document.getElementById('popup-btn-1').addEventListener('click', function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {script: 'popup-btn-1.js'});
    });
});
```

content_script.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = chrome.extension.getURL('scenarios/' + request.script);
    script.onload = function() {
        this.remove();
    };
    (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
});
```

As you can see I bind an event listener to a button (popup window) that will inject a certain script when I click the button. What I would like to do is to trigger one of these steps via CLI (not browser console), so I can automate things. Please note that URL matching is not sufficient for me, as I have different scripts that might or might not be injected, depending on what I want to test.

Is this possible in any way?

Comment: See [Passing information from command line into Chrome extension](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34630827)

Comment: You can also set up a primitive local http server that autoupdates its contents from some disk folder, where you can store a file with instructions for your extension via CLI. The extension will periodically check that `localhost` page using XMLHttpRequest or Fetch API.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing information from command line into Chrome extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629312/passing-information-from-command-line-into-chrome-extension)